# MVC View Model Intellisense / Compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one Library with my ORM and am working with a MVC Application.  I have a problem where the pages won't compile because the Views can't see the Model's properties (which are inherited from lower level base classes).  They system throws a compile error saying that

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' 
>     accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using
>     directive or an assembly reference?)

implying that the View is not seeing the model.  In the Controller I have full access to the Model and have check the Inherits from portion of the view to validate the correct type is being passed.

**Controller:**

```
return View(new TeraViral_Blog());
```

**View:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<com.models.TeraViral_Blog>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
 Index2
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Index2</h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            ID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.ID) %>
        </p>
    </fieldset>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Casting the item works so it's got the right type.  I'd just really like to keep the casts from bloating the view.

((com.models.TeraViral_Blog)Model).ID

Comment: Are your models declared public? I am imagining a scenario where they would be internal and the views are operating in a different namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your web.config of your Views folder look for the "namespaces" node and add your Model's namespace there:

```
<namespaces>
  <add namespace="com.models"/>
</namespaces>
```